# How do I find non-repeating and non-inverted value pairs in the following nodes of project?

Tags: xml, web-scraping, xquery

I have the following result so far form a query on the xml files.

```
<results>
  <project>
    <pnumber>1</pnumber>
    <workers>
      <essn>123456789</essn>
      <essn>453453453</essn>

    </workers>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pnumber>2</pnumber>
    <workers>
      <essn>123456789</essn>
      <essn>333445555</essn>
      <essn>453453453</essn>
    </workers>
  </project>
  ...
```

And so on for 6 projects (pnumber). I need to find pairs of values of essn for values of each project and list them for workers. I cannot have repeating pairs or inverted pairs in the results.

Iv tried modifying the distinct-value below to show pairs after determining which pairs are distinct.

```
let $items := (1,2,4,4,5,5)
let $unique-items := distinct-values($items)
return
   <result>   

      <items>
      {
         for $item in $unique-items
         return <item>{$item}</item>
      }
      </items>


   </result>
```

I am just getting the unique values in the set.

I use this to get where I am now,

```
<results>
  {
    for $project in doc("../company/project.xml")//project
    where $project/pnumber=*
    return
     <project>
      {$project/pnumber}
       {  
              let $works_on := doc("../company/works_on.xml")//works_on[pno = $project/pnumber]
              return
             <workers>
              {$works_on/essn}
                  </workers>
      } 
     </project>   
  }
</results>
```

The result should look like this

```
<results>
  <project>
    <pnumber>1</pnumber>
    <workers>
      <pair1>
      <essn>123456789</essn>
      <essn>453453453</essn>
      </pair1>
    </workers>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pnumber>2</pnumber>
    <workers>

      <pair1>
      <essn>123456789</essn>
      <essn>333445555</essn>
       </pair1>

      <pair2>
      <essn>453453453</essn>
      <essn>333445555</essn>
       </pair2>

       <pair3>

       <essn>123456789</essn>
       <essn>453453453</essn>

        </pair3>

    </workers>
  </project>
  ...
```

Comment: Is "I cannot have repeating pairs or inverted pairs in the results" a statement on how your input data looks? Or a requirement for the output you want to create? It would also ease our task to understand the problem if you used simpler sample data, I am struggling to see whether `<essn>453453453</essn>` and `<essn>453453453</essn>` are repeated or unique values. Also consider to tell us which version of XQuery you work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given sample data I think the query

```
<results>
{
    for $project in results/project
    return
        <project>
        {
            $project/pnumber,
            <workers>
            {
                for $worker at $pos in $project/workers/essn
                for $other-worker in $project/workers/essn[position() gt $pos]
                count $p
                return
                    <pair index="{$p}">
                    {
                        $worker,
                        $other-worker
                    }
                    </pair>
            }
            </workers>
        }
        </project>
}
</results>
```

creates the right pairs at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kD.

I am not sure whether the requirement to not repeat data is not a step you simply want or at could ensure by replacing

```
let $works_on := doc("../company/works_on.xml")//works_on[pno = $project/pnumber]
          return
         <workers>
          {$works_on/essn}
              </workers>
```

with

```
 let $works_on := distinct-values(doc("../company/works_on.xml")//works_on[pno = $project/pnumber]/essn)
          return
         <workers>
            <essn>{.}</essn>
          </workers>
```